# Advanced Settings, Permissions for Calendars in Sharepoint2010

Tags: list, permissions, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I have a question regarding the set up of a calendar.. I have a group work calendar that I am having issues with permissions. I want a user to be able to edit/delete a reservation they have made on the calendar, but **not** edit/delete a reservation someone else has made on the calendar. The group that these users are in for permissions currently have read and contribute.

I went into the advanced settings for the list and have selected this option--
[image]

But, people in the contribute group are still able to delete other people's reservations. Please help! Thank you :)

Comment: are there any permission levels higher than contribute? if so they may be able to delete items.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to achieve this:

1. Create a **custom permission** without edit or delete and assign it
   to the list
2. **Through a workflow** revoke the permission after item
   has been added (only works with 2010 Workflow

I would prefer the option one:

1. Under Site Setting, ==> Site Permission, Click Permission Level

[image]

2. Click the 'Contribute' Permissions and at the bottom Click Copy Permission Level.  It will create a new permission level, uncheck 'Edit and Delete Items'.

[image]

3. Break the permission inheritance for the list and assign the new permission level to the list.

[image]